# How to Block Traffic From a Single IP in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-vpc

Our server being hammered by traffic from some particular IP. It was causing a 20x increase in traffic to some URLs. So I wanted to block all traffic from that single IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we can block traffic from single IP or IP range. Please follow below steps to do this

> Open **VPC** dashboard

[image]

> Open the **Network ACLs** view

[image]

> Open the ACL editor

1. Select the subnet to which your EC2 instances or load balancers are connected.
2. Click **Inbound Rules**
3. Click **Edit**

[image]

> Add a rule to block the traffic/IP

You will now see the ACL editor. On the last row, you can add a new rule.

[image]

Here is how you should fill out the fields:

## Rule

Use any number less than 100, which is the number of the default accept-all rule. This is important because rules are evaluated in order, and your rule needs to come before the default.

## Type

Select “All traffic” or Particular Protocol which you want to Block

## Source

The CIDR you want to block. To match a single IP address, enter it here and append /32. For example, I blocked `22.87.45.187/32`

## Allow/Deny

Select “DENY”

Now **click Save** and you should see the updated rules table.

Fore more details visit https://www.serverkaka.com/2018/05/block-traffic-from-single-ip-in-aws.html

---

#### UPDATE: How to do it in CLI

> NOTE: This example command includes `--dry-run` option, so it is safe to run. It will not create *NACL* rule. Run it without this option, if you want to apply it.

```
aws ec2 create-network-acl-entry --dry-run --network-acl-id acl-146adb6f --ingress --rule-number 20 --protocol tcp --port-range From=80,To=80 --cidr-block 22.87.45.187/32 --rule-action deny
```

More examples:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-network-acl-entry.html#examples

Comment: This can also be done via command line. Additionally you can use Fail2Ban to detect the problematic source and then use your own custom script to assert the NACL rule to block that IP. As well you can incorporate additional scripts to release after X (e.g. 30 minutes) the rule. Sorry, I cannot post an example as I was not allowed to copy the work I did to create just this.